# Can I achieve Single Sign-On in Auth0 if I use my custom database?

Tags: single-sign-on, auth0

Does Single Sign-on in Auth0 requires us to use Auth0 Database? If I use my custom database (and not migrate users to Auth0 Database), can I achieve Single Sign-on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can as per [this](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db).

"Auth0 provides templates for most common databases, such as: ASP.NET Membership Provider, MongoDB, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLServer, Windows Azure SQL Database, and for a web service accessed by Basic Auth. Essentially, you can connect to any kind of database or web service with a custom script."

Comment: thanks. I understand that auth0 can authenticate users using a custom database, but I think it doesn't necessary mean it achieves SSO. In other words - it acheives authentication, but not SSO.

Comment: Given that the whole point of Auth0 is SSO I would guess Yes but I've never tried it.

Comment: SSO is between the user and the authorization server. The connection between the authorization server and the database is irrelevant.